# Validation error in Pydantic with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I get errors with fields validation when using different model schemas for input and output in post-request.

Here is the code of my router:

```
@router.post('/sign-up/', response_model=UserOutSchema)
def register(user: UserInSchema, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(user.password1.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    db_user = UserModel(
        name=user.name, surname=user.surname, email=user.email, hashed_password=hashed_password
    )
    session.add(db_user)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user
```

schemas:

```
class UserIn(BaseModel):
    name: str
    surname: str
    email: EmailStr
    password1: str
    password2: str

    @model_validator(mode='after')
    def check_passwords_match(self):
        pw1 = self.password1
        pw2 = self.password2

        if pw1 is not None and pw2 is not None and pw1 != pw2:
            raise ValueError('Passwords do not match..')
        return self

    @classmethod
    @field_validator('email')
    def validate_email_taken(cls):
        email = cls.email
        query = db.query(UserModel).filter(UserModel.email == email).first()
        if query:
            raise ValueError('Email already exists')
        return cls


class UserOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    surname: str
    email: EmailStr
    time_created: datetime
    email_confirmed: bool
    is_admin: bool
    is_stuff: bool
```

`UserOutSchema` here is alias name for `UserOut` declared in import statement
database models:

```
class AbstractModel(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)


class User(AbstractModel):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    surname: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(70), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    hashed_password: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)

    time_created = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())

    email_confirmed: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_seller: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=False)
    is_admin: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=False)
    is_stuff: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=False)

    seller: Mapped['Seller'] = relationship(back_populates='user', uselist=False)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'User<{self.id}> {self.name} + {self.surname}'


class Seller(AbstractModel):
    __tablename__ = 'sellers'

    user: Mapped['User'] = relationship(back_populates='seller', uselist=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.id'))

    mobile: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    company_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True, nullable=False)
    company_description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=False)

    bank_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    tin: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)     # Tax Identification Number
    bic: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(9), nullable=False)           # Bank Identified Code
    trrc: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(9), nullable=False)          # Tax Registration Reason Code
    an: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)           # AccountNumber

    passport_scan: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(130), nullable=False, unique=True)
    tc_scan: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(130), nullable=False, unique=True)       # Trademark Certificate

    additional: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True)
    time_created = mapped_column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())

    # If approved, is allowed to sell products
    is_approved: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'User<{self.user_id}> Seller<{self.id}>'
```

and the traceback:

```
weatherforecast-web-1      | RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
weatherforecast-web-1      | INFO:     172.20.0.1:51818 - "POST /users/sign-up/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
weatherforecast-web-1      | ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
weatherforecast-web-1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
weatherforecast-web-1      |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
weatherforecast-web-1      |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 1115, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     raise exc
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     raise exc
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     raise e
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
weatherforecast-web-1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
weatherforecast-web-1      |     response = await func(request)
weatherforecast-web-1      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 292, in app
weatherforecast-web-1      |     content = await serialize_response(
weatherforecast-web-1      |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
weatherforecast-web-1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 155, in serialize_response
weatherforecast-web-1      |     raise ResponseValidationError(
weatherforecast-web-1      | fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 5 validation errors:
weatherforecast-web-1      |   {'type': 'int_type', 'loc': ('response', 'id'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid integer', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/int_type'}
weatherforecast-web-1      |   {'type': 'datetime_type', 'loc': ('response', 'time_created'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid datetime', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/datetime_type'}
weatherforecast-web-1      |   {'type': 'bool_type', 'loc': ('response', 'email_confirmed'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid boolean', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/bool_type'}
weatherforecast-web-1      |   {'type': 'bool_type', 'loc': ('response', 'is_admin'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid boolean', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/bool_type'}
weatherforecast-web-1      |   {'type': 'bool_type', 'loc': ('response', 'is_stuff'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid boolean', 'input': None, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/bool_type'}
```

I would be very grateful if someone helps me. I have already search for the solutions and documentation materials but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: If you want SQLAlchemy models to be automagically converted, you'll have to configure `from_attributes` on your model (you can do it on a base model that you inherit in all your output models if you want to use that). You do this by defining a `model_config` property: `model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)`: https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/concepts/config/#change-behaviour-globally

Comment: @MatsLindh, still does not work for some reason, unfortunately

Comment: @Chris, oops, sorry, it's my fault that I forget to include import statements in my question, where I import `UserOut` as `UserOutSchema`

Comment: @Chris, yes, I understand that the response doesn't match the `response_model`, but I don't understand why. Pydantic models have similar fields as `SQLAlchemy` models (e.g. `bool` in pydantic and `bool` type for database). But for some reason it appears that I get `None` instead of data type that is specified for the model. And it is unclear to me why it is `None` even though I have default values in DB

Comment: trying to solve the issue, I figured out that the data I send to the endpoint creating the user is not saved  to the DB for some reason, probably there are some problems within postgresql configuration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and it's pretty straightforward. The problem was that I had to use `await` syntax before `session.commit()` and `session.refresh(db_user)` as I am using an asynchronous database driver `asyncpg`. However when fixed the issue I ran into another problem, that I don't get data saved to the Database as I passed `hashed_password` variable with type of `bytes` instead of `str` expected. When I converted the `hashed_password` variable to `str`, it appeared to be working.